# What theory unifies the electroweak and the strong forces?

Tags: standard-model, electroweak, strong-force

As the title itself suggests, here's my question: What theory unifies the electroweak and the strong forces?

Comment: How about some googling?

Comment: You need to read around the subject a bit, and come back to us with a better targetted questions. The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Unified_Theory) is a good place to start.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it [shows insufficient effort](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

The [standard model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics is the unification of electroweak and strong interactions:

> The Standard Model of particle physics is a theory concerning the electromagnetic, weak, and strong nuclear interactions, which mediate the dynamics of the known subatomic particles. It was developed throughout the latter half of the 20th century, as a collaborative effort of scientists around the world. The current formulation was finalized in the mid-1970s upon experimental confirmation of the existence of quarks. Since then, discoveries of the top quark (1995), the tau neutrino (2000), and more recently the Higgs boson (2013), have given further credence to the Standard Model. Because of its success in explaining a wide variety of experimental results, the Standard Model is sometimes regarded as a "theory of almost everything".